# Troubles with "Stretch To" constraint

Tags: constraints

Still feels a newbie with blender, so I have also dummy question. But while looking for the solutions, it looks that I'm not the only one. I'm trying to follow Ray Mairlot's [You tube: Blender Tutorial: Laser Cutting Text Effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIFC7NA0tSs).

At 4:30 he adds the "Stretch to" constraint, and hit the same problem than many others. The object turn to away from the source object. See my **simplified** example:

[image]

Like on the other solutions, he rotate the object to -90 and bang! it is in correct position.

The answer I'm looking for is, what is actually causing this? Why rotation of the object should fix a problem? I mean, what is the error in a first place we all made to cause this?

And yes, I did not manage to get this fixed :D No matter how much I rotate it, it never follow the object. Some proposed to use "Copy rotation" constraint as well, but that was not helpful.

regards
Pepi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the *Stretch* constraint uses the object's Y axis as the one that points to the *Target* (and deforms the object). So if your object's Y axis already points towards the target it won't rotate, but if the Y axis is 90°, the object will rotate 90°. So, depending on how your object is oriented, you may need to correct its orientation.

[image]

Comment: big thanks for this. Strange limitation, but need to learn to rotate the object before start stretching.